# How to search a node and remove its child elements in an xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml in the following format:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="font-family: 'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="400">
    <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels">
        <text style="position: absolute; color: #606060; font-size: 11px; cursor: default; fill: #606060" opacity="1" z="32" x="107" y="300" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(45 107 300)" text-anchor="start">
            <tspan>% Service FTE</tspan>
            <tspan x="107" dy="15">Offshore/Total</tspan>
            <tspan x="107" dy="15">Service FTE</tspan>
        </text>        
        <text style="position: absolute; color: #606060; font-size: 11px; cursor: default; fill: #606060" opacity="1" z="32" x="493" y="300" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(45 493 300)" text-anchor="start">
            <tspan>Setup costs as %</tspan>
            <tspan x="493" dy="15">of sales EAR</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>        
    <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels">
        <text style="position: absolute; color: #606060; font-size: 11px; cursor: default; fill: #606060" opacity="1" z="29" x="64" y="289" text-anchor="end">0</text>
        <text style="position: absolute; color: #606060; font-size: 11px; cursor: default; fill: #606060" opacity="1" z="15" x="62" y="238" text-anchor="end">25</text>
    </g>        
    <g style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; white-space: nowrap; cursor: default; padding-top: 0px" class="highcharts-tooltip"  transform="translate(0,-9999)">
        <path d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)" stroke-opacity="0.05"></path>        
        <path d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0" fill="rgba(249, 249, 249, .85)" stroke-width="1"></path>
        <text style="position: absolute; color: #333333; font-size: 12px; fill: #333333" x="8"  y="21"></text>
    </g>
    <text style="position: absolute; color: #909090; font-size: 9px; cursor: pointer; fill: #909090" x="590"  y="395" text-anchor="end"></text>
</svg>
```

I would like to update certain nodes like 
    tspan x="493" dy="15"
etc and remove the last node and last but one node with its childs if there are any using c#.

Please help.

Comment: Show us your code and ask where are you facing the problem

Comment: In particular, I'd recommend using LINQ to XML, as a really nice XML API. It should be easy to achieve what you're after - try it, and edit your question with what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through each node did the job. Thanks all